# android level-list warning that make my app crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am new in Android developing, I am reading "For Dummies Android Application Development. All-in-One For Dummies" book and I have encountered a problem.
I am trying to create a level-list that contains image for each level, here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plain" android:maxLevel="0" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pepperoni" android:maxLevel="1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/extracheese" android:maxLevel="2" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pep_extracheese" android:maxLevel="3" />
</level-list>
```

This is the hierarchy of package explorer:

[image]

No in activity_main.xml when I try to add imgView I am getting this warnings:

```
Failed to convert D:\Android\test1\res\drawable\plain.jpg into a drawable
Failed to parse file D:\Android\test1\res\drawable\levels.xml
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

here is the code in  activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/new_layout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
        android:src="@drawable/levels" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the logCat:

```
?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
10-28 17:14:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:0m:59.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:14:22.105: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{428a1278: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
10-28 17:14:22.185: I/ActivityManager(427): No longer want com.asus.keyboard (pid 6303): hidden #16
10-28 17:14:22.195: W/ActivityManager(427): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.keyboard/.KeyboardService in 5000ms
10-28 17:14:27.235: I/ActivityManager(427): Start proc com.asus.keyboard for service com.asus.keyboard/.KeyboardService: pid=6690 uid=1000 gids={3003, 1015, 1028, 3002, 3001, 1006, 3007}
10-28 17:14:27.235: I/ActivityManager(427): --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
10-28 17:14:27.275: E/(6690): fail to touchpad on
10-28 17:15:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:0m:59.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:15:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{429003e0: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
10-28 17:15:47.025: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:15:47.025: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:15:47.025: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:15:47.025: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:15:47.055: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:96 plugged:0
10-28 17:15:47.055: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:15:47.055: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 96, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:15:47.055: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:15:47.055: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:15:47.065: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:16:20.855: W/ThrottleService(427): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
10-28 17:16:21.785: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 42986988 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{4279aca8: PendingIntentRecord{429da220 com.android.email startService}}
10-28 17:16:21.825: I/Email(32306): ReconcilePopImapAccountsSync: start
10-28 17:16:21.835: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{42c68558 type 2 com.android.email} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:9m:59.0s
10-28 17:16:21.855: D/AlarmManager(427): Removed alarm Alarm{42c68558 type 2 com.android.email} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
10-28 17:16:21.855: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{42af10d8 type 2 com.android.email} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:14m:59.0s
10-28 17:16:21.875: I/Email(32306): ReconcilePopImapAccountsSync: done
10-28 17:16:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:0m:59.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:16:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{427482a8: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
10-28 17:16:22.185: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): Making GetUserAlertsRequest
10-28 17:16:24.365: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): Parsing JSON=
10-28 17:16:24.365: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): {"Timestamp":"2012-10-28T15:16:22.403Z","Ack":"Success","Build":"E777_CORE_BUNDLED_14927770_R1","Version":"777","SessionData":"AQAAATqVN+gAAA1TSUQ9NTkzMTgxMDl8U1Q9MXwxfExBQ1RWPTEzNTE0MzczODIzODh8RUhXTT02MTg0MTMxNzE3fFRJRFg9MXxMSVVQPTEzNTE0MjE2MDMzMjV8UExIUz1bXUX8bkYc6+LfU4Y3v7F6KKPQssgs"}
10-28 17:16:24.375: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): Call was success but no alerts
10-28 17:16:24.375: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): Got response ackCode=1
10-28 17:16:24.375: D/GetUserAlerts(29608): Ack Success, session data=AQAAATqVN+gAAA1TSUQ9NTkzMTgxMDl8U1Q9MXwxfExBQ1RWPTEzNTE0MzczODIzODh8RUhXTT02MTg0MTMxNzE3fFRJRFg9MXxMSVVQPTEzNTE0MjE2MDMzMjV8UExIUz1bXUX8bkYc6+LfU4Y3v7F6KKPQssgs
10-28 17:17:22.095: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:0m:59.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:17:22.105: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{428d07b8: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
10-28 17:17:47.295: D/BatteryService(427): level:97 scale:100 status:4 health:2 present:true dock_status:1 dock_level:0 dock_ac_online:false voltage: 8 temperature: 280 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:false icon:17302867 invalid charger:0
10-28 17:17:47.365: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:17:47.365: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:17:47.365: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:17:47.365: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:17:47.385: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:97 plugged:0
10-28 17:17:47.385: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:17:47.395: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 97, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:17:47.395: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:17:47.395: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:17:47.395: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:18:21.707: D/PowerManagerService(427): forceUserActivityLocked when usb changes
10-28 17:18:21.707: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'StayOnWhilePluggedIn Screen Dim' flags [screen_dim]
10-28 17:18:21.707: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'StayOnWhilePluggedIn Partial' flags [partial]
10-28 17:18:21.707: D/PowerManagerService(427): IntentUserActivityLocked, send wakeup intent to Keyguard
10-28 17:18:21.737: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:18:21.737: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:18:21.737: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:18:21.737: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/KeyguardViewMediator(427): Receive wakeup source, keyguard show:true
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): range : 114 140 102 104
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): result : 140 255 104 255
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Screen Bright {false -> true}
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Screen turned on mScreenOffTime=1639932ms Battery<C,V>: <97,8>
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Acquire UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=1
10-28 17:18:21.747: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Acquire UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=2
10-28 17:18:21.757: E/Sensors(427): enable - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4) dis -> en
10-28 17:18:21.757: V/Sensors(427): enabled_sensors: 16 dmp_started: 0
10-28 17:18:21.757: V/Sensors(427): Starting DMP
10-28 17:18:21.757: E/(427): /home/mcaramello/Software/MPL/branch-CAN-4.1.0/mlsdk/mltools/batch/mlsdk-rel-android-src-CONFIDENTIAL/mldmp/mlsupervisor_9axis.c|inv_enable_9x_fusion_legacy|299 returning 1
10-28 17:18:21.757: E/Sensors(427): Error while trying to enable 9 axis sensor fusion : 1
10-28 17:18:21.767: I/MPL-mldl_cfg_mpu:(427): inv_mpu_resume(,,,,0070) -> 0070
10-28 17:18:21.767: V/Sensors(427): setDelay - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4), rate 200 ms (5.00 Hz)
10-28 17:18:21.767: V/Sensors(427): set fifo rate - divider : 39, delay : 200 ms (5.00 Hz)
10-28 17:18:21.767: I/MPL-fifo(427): Actual ODR: 25000 mHz
10-28 17:18:21.767: V/Sensors(427): setDelay - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4), rate 66 ms (15.00 Hz)
10-28 17:18:21.767: V/Sensors(427): set fifo rate - divider : 13, delay : 66 ms (15.00 Hz)
10-28 17:18:21.767: I/MPL-fifo(427): Actual ODR: 25000 mHz
10-28 17:18:21.827: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: sending ordered bcast for ACTION_SCREEN_ON
10-28 17:18:21.837: D/Ethernet(427): Connect is not possible because : ETHERNET not ENABLE, sleep can sleep, 
10-28 17:18:21.847: D/AudioFlinger(121): SRS_Processing::ParamsSet
10-28 17:18:21.907: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=1
10-28 17:18:21.927: W/TAG(699): onSurfaceCreated
10-28 17:18:21.927: I/TAG(699):  calling onSharedPreferenceChanged from onSurfaceCreated
10-28 17:18:21.927: W/TAG(699): onSharedPreferenceChanged, key: null
10-28 17:18:21.927: W/TAG(699): onSurfaceChanged
10-28 17:18:21.927: I/TAG(699):  onSurfaceChanged - surfaceW: -1
10-28 17:18:21.927: I/TAG(699):  onSurfaceChanged - width: 800
10-28 17:18:21.957: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:97 plugged:0
10-28 17:18:21.957: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:18:21.957: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 97, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:18:21.957: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:18:21.957: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:18:21.957: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:18:22.047: D/PowerManagerService(427): range : 114 140 102 104
10-28 17:18:22.047: D/PowerManagerService(427): result : 140 255 104 255
10-28 17:18:22.047: I/WindowManager(427): Lock screen displayed!
10-28 17:18:22.047: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=0
10-28 17:18:22.057: D/dalvikvm(119): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-28 17:18:22.077: D/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 6% free 6003K/6339K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
10-28 17:18:22.077: I/ActivityManager(427): Start proc com.asus.pcsynclauncher for broadcast com.asus.pcsynclauncher/.activity.USBReceiver: pid=6722 uid=10054 gids={3003, 1028}
10-28 17:18:22.087: D/dalvikvm(119): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-28 17:18:22.107: D/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 6003K/6339K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 19ms
10-28 17:18:22.107: D/dalvikvm(119): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-28 17:18:22.117: D/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 6003K/6339K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 18ms
10-28 17:18:22.117: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:0m:59.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:18:22.117: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{42ee55a0: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
10-28 17:18:22.147: D/SurfaceFlinger(118): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x40d24bb8
10-28 17:18:22.157: I/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): USB Receiver : android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
10-28 17:18:22.157: D/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): usb state is not connected
10-28 17:18:22.277: I/ActivityManager(427): Start proc com.asus.UpdateLauncher for broadcast com.asus.UpdateLauncher/.UpdateLauncherIntentReceiver: pid=6747 uid=10070 gids={1028}
10-28 17:18:22.277: I/ActivityManager(427): No longer want com.google.android.apps.maps:GoogleLocationService (pid 6316): hidden #16
10-28 17:18:22.297: I/LocationManagerService(427): remove passive (pid 427), next minTime = 0
10-28 17:18:22.297: W/ActivityManager(427): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService in 5000ms
10-28 17:18:22.307: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'StayOnWhilePluggedIn Screen Dim' flags [screen_dim]
10-28 17:18:22.317: D/PowerManagerService(427): forceUserActivityLocked when usb changes
10-28 17:18:22.317: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'StayOnWhilePluggedIn Partial' flags [partial]
10-28 17:18:22.317: D/PowerManagerService(427): IntentUserActivityLocked, send wakeup intent to Keyguard
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/KeyguardViewMediator(427): Receive wakeup source, keyguard show:true
10-28 17:18:22.327: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:97 plugged:0
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 97, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:18:22.327: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:18:22.397: I/ActivityManager(427): No longer want com.facebook.katana (pid 6235): hidden #16
10-28 17:18:22.537: I/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): USB Receiver : android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
10-28 17:18:22.537: D/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): usb connected
10-28 17:18:22.537: D/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): extras: Bundle[{configured=false, adb=true, connected=true, mtp=true}]
10-28 17:18:22.597: I/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): USB Receiver : android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
10-28 17:18:22.597: D/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): usb connected
10-28 17:18:22.597: D/LauncherUsbReceiver(6722): extras: Bundle[{configured=true, adb=true, connected=true, mtp=true}]
10-28 17:18:22.607: D/MtpService(4859): addStorageLocked 65537 /storage/sdcard0
10-28 17:18:22.607: D/MtpService(4859): starting MTP server in MTP mode
10-28 17:18:22.607: D/MtpService(4859): addStorageLocked 65537 /storage/sdcard0
10-28 17:18:22.727: I/FPS(699): FPS 0.02308548268555613
10-28 17:18:24.087: I/FPS(699): FPS 44.11313843658626
10-28 17:18:24.527: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:18:24.527: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:18:24.527: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:18:24.527: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:18:24.537: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:97 plugged:0
10-28 17:18:24.537: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:18:24.537: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 97, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:18:24.537: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:18:24.537: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:18:24.537: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:18:25.347: I/FPS(699): FPS 47.6573247719597
10-28 17:18:26.587: I/FPS(699): FPS 48.46542315160954
10-28 17:18:26.727: D/PowerSaving(5075): onReceived
10-28 17:18:26.727: D/PowerSaving(5075): power_unplugged
10-28 17:18:26.727: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167
10-28 17:18:26.727: D/PowerSaving(5075): back light = 167 , back light = 108.549995
10-28 17:18:26.747: I/fdhttpd(6378): battery level:97 plugged:0
10-28 17:18:26.747: D/LowBatteryService(6466): onReceive:Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
10-28 17:18:26.747: D/LowBatteryService(6466): mAcOnline = false, mDeviceBatteryLevel = 97, mDockBatteryLevel = 0, mDockBatteryStatus = 0
10-28 17:18:26.747: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is higher than threshold, no need to apply
10-28 17:18:26.747: D/LowBatteryService(6466): Battery level is good, no need to apply low battery config.
10-28 17:18:26.747: D/DockManagerService(6466): mLastAcOnline:false mAcOnline:false
10-28 17:18:27.317: I/ActivityManager(427): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:GoogleLocationService for service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService: pid=6783 uid=10026 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
10-28 17:18:27.467: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 69K, 3% free 6439K/6599K, paused 20ms+4ms, total 47ms
10-28 17:18:27.467: D/dalvikvm(6783): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
10-28 17:18:27.897: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 74K, 3% free 6870K/7047K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 32ms
10-28 17:18:27.917: I/FPS(699): FPS 45.276253058033596
10-28 17:18:27.987: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 58K, 3% free 7345K/7495K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 52ms
10-28 17:18:27.987: D/dalvikvm(6783): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
10-28 17:18:28.357: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 225K, 5% free 7605K/7943K, paused 14ms+12ms, total 59ms
10-28 17:18:28.527: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 4% free 7989K/8263K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 47ms
10-28 17:18:28.647: I/LocationManagerService(427): request passive (pid 6783) 0 0
10-28 17:18:28.767: D/dalvikvm(6783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 769K, 11% free 7878K/8775K, paused 34ms+20ms, total 108ms
10-28 17:18:29.157: I/FPS(699): FPS 48.33112621190299
10-28 17:18:30.387: I/FPS(699): FPS 48.7477515099616
10-28 17:18:31.627: I/FPS(699): FPS 48.44589602703281
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): range : 114 140 102 104
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): result : 140 255 104 255
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: 'keyguard' releaseWakeLock when screen locked
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Screen Bright {true -> false}
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Screen turned off mScreenOnTime=10585ms Battery<C,V>: <97,8>
10-28 17:18:32.337: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Acquire UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=1
10-28 17:18:32.347: D/SurfaceFlinger(118): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x40d24bb8
10-28 17:18:32.357: E/Sensors(427): enable - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4) en -> dis
10-28 17:18:32.357: V/Sensors(427): enabled_sensors: 0 dmp_started: 1
10-28 17:18:32.357: V/Sensors(427): Stopping DMP
10-28 17:18:32.357: W/Sensors(427): Cannot disable 9 axis sensor fusion - already disabled
10-28 17:18:32.357: I/MPL-mldl_cfg_mpu:(427): inv_mpu_suspend(,,,,7fff) -> 0000
10-28 17:18:32.357: V/Sensors(427): setDelay - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4), rate 66 ms (15.00 Hz)
10-28 17:18:32.367: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: sending ordered bcast for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
10-28 17:18:32.387: D/Ethernet(427): Screen Off connect_policy = 0 ; bTethered = false
10-28 17:18:32.387: D/Ethernet(427): Screen Off
10-28 17:18:32.397: D/AudioFlinger(121): SRS_Processing::ParamsSet
10-28 17:18:32.467: D/PowerManagerService(427): @PowerManagement: Release UWL 'sleep_broadcast' flags [partial] refcount=0
10-28 17:18:32.487: V/TransportControlView(427): Create TCV com.android.internal.widget.TransportControlView@4284b508
10-28 17:18:32.547: V/LockPatternKeyguardView(427): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$4@42950e40 to 8388608
10-28 17:18:32.547: V/LockPatternKeyguardView(427): Set visibility on com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView$4@42950e40 to 8388608
10-28 17:19:00.247: D/dalvikvm(427): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1559K, 39% free 15198K/24903K, paused 5ms+13ms, total 176ms
10-28 17:19:00.507: D/dalvikvm(6653): GC_CONCURRENT freed 275K, 7% free 6361K/6791K, paused 16ms+3ms, total 42ms
10-28 17:19:22.077: D/dalvikvm(800): GC_CONCURRENT freed 662K, 19% free 7374K/9031K, paused 27ms+4ms, total 104ms
10-28 17:19:22.097: D/AlarmManager(427): Added alarm Alarm{428747c8 type 2 com.ebay.mobile} type:ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP when: After 0h:1m:0.0s repeatInterval: 0h:1m:0.0s
10-28 17:19:22.097: D/AlarmManager(427): Triggered Alarm 428747c8 ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP IntentSender{42e45520: PendingIntentRecord{42aa6270 com.ebay.mobile broadcastIntent}}
```

when I try to run this app it's crashing. Can you help me understand why it is crashing and help me fix it.

Comment: Logcat please. Will be helpful to analyze the problem.

Comment: Ohh.. You should've added only relevant logs. Anyways, I'll try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but after restarting eclipse it worked
Thanks